# Close windows in reverse order of creation

Tags: autoit

I have a program with a main window and multiple other windows and want to use autoit to close these windows. The main window however refuses to close if other windows of the program are open and creates a warning message.

To avoid this, I want to close the other windows first.

Because of the way the program is written, the windows are NOT in a parent-child relationship, so I cannot use "EnumChildWindows" in "user32.dll".

So my other option would be to obtain the order or time the windows were created at, and close them in reversed order. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to get it by the process.  The function below will return the z-order of the windows, as far as I know, without you tracking the "creation time" of the windows themselves from within your own code, you won't get a solution that can do that.

```
#include <WinAPIProc.au3>
#include <WinAPISys.au3>

#region - Example
Global $gahWnd[3]
For $i = 0 To 2
    $gahWnd[$i] = GUICreate("Example " & $i)
    GUISetState(@SW_SHOW, $gahWnd[$i])
Next


Global $gaExample = _WinGetByProc(@AutoItPID)
If @error Then Exit 2
Sleep(3000) ; so you can at least see the windows were created

; windows are returned in the "last z-order"
;  so they'll be returned "Example 2, Example 1, Example 0"
;  This makes it easy to close all but the first one

; use -1 to keep the first window created
For $i = 1 To $gaExample[0] - 1
    ConsoleWrite("Closing: " & $gaExample[$i] & ":" & WinGetTitle($gaExample[$i]) & @CRLF)
    WinClose($gaExample[$i])
Next

Global $gaMsg
While 1
    $gaMsg = GUIGetMsg(1)
    Switch $gaMsg[1]
        Case $gahWnd[0]
            Switch $gaMsg[0]
                Case -3
                    Exit
            EndSwitch
        Case $gahWnd[1]
            Switch $gaMsg[0]
                Case -3
                    GUIDelete($gahWnd[1])
            EndSwitch
        Case $gahWnd[2]
            Switch $gaMsg[0]
                Case -3
                    GUIDelete($gahWnd[2])
            EndSwitch
    EndSwitch
WEnd
#EndRegion - Example

; pass the exe or the process id
Func _WinGetByProc($vExe)

    ; will return pid if exe name sent or validate if pid is sent
    Local $iPID = ProcessExists($vExe)
    If Not ProcessExists($iPID) Then
        Return SetError(1, 0, 0)
    EndIf

    ; enum desktop window only (top-level-windows)
    Local $ahWnds = _WinAPI_EnumDesktopWindows(_WinAPI_GetThreadDesktop( _
                _WinAPI_GetCurrentThreadId()))
    If @error Or Not IsArray($ahWnds) Then
        Return SetError(2, 0, 0)
    EndIf

    Local $aExeContainer[11], $iDim
    For $iwnd = 1 To $ahWnds[0][0]
        ; compare windows pid with our pid
        If (WinGetProcess(HWnd($ahWnds[$iwnd][0])) = $iPID) Then
            $iDim += 1
            ; sanity check, be sure the array has the right number of indexes
            If (Mod($iDim, 10) = 0) Then
                ReDim $aExeContainer[$iDim + 10]
            EndIf
            $aExeContainer[$iDim] = HWnd($ahWnds[$iwnd][0])
        EndIf
    Next

    ; if there were no matches return
    If Not $iDim Then
        Return SetError(3, 0, 0)
    EndIf

    ; trim array and set number found in the zero index
    ReDim $aExeContainer[$iDim + 1]
    $aExeContainer[0] = $iDim

    Return $aExeContainer
EndFunc
```

Comment: sadly, I don't think the program locks the windows in z-order. However, it might still work in most use cases... I will try that on monday. (And will check this as the answer if no better solutions comes up) Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the application that does this readily available or do you have another app you know demonstrates the issue you're running into?

Comment: Sorry, no. The program in question is not publicly available. And since this is the first time I am Involved in UI-Automation, I am not aware of any other application that does this.